# JAVA: How come I cannot have more than two JLabels in the same vertical position (different horizontal positions)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I am creating a GUI with three labels. I used the setBounds method on each label, and the first two labels are in the x and y positions that I passed in the parameters. However, the third label is simply sitting at the left.

Here is my code:

```
principleLabel = new JLabel(); 
principleLabel.setText("Principle");
principleLabel.setBounds(101, 10, 100, 50);
frame.getContentPane().add(principleLabel); 

rateLabel = new JLabel(); 
rateLabel.setText("Rate (Percentage)");
rateLabel.setBounds(295, 10, 150, 50);
frame.getContentPane().add(rateLabel); 

yearsLabel = new JLabel(); 
yearsLabel.setText("Years");
yearsLabel.setBounds(555, 10, 50, 50);
frame.getContentPane().add(yearsLabel);
```

I tried putting the labels in different orders, and I saw it is always the one written last that is behaving weirdly.

[image: My GUI]

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: depends on your layout. A simple FlowLayout will position the lables next to each other(with no need for setBounds)

Answer (score -1):

A guide to using Absolute Positioning can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).

The layout manager for the container should be set to null. (Can't see if you are doing this or not from the code shown.)
The setbounds method is used for all the components in the container. (Looks like you are doing this.)
The repaint method of the container needs to be called.

If you do any resizing, or if the component doesn't fit within the bounds of the container, I'm not clear what exactly will happen.

If I were laying things out, I'd probably try to go a route that is easy in JavaFX, where one makes use of a combination of nested HBox and VBox layouts. It's been a while since using Swing, but I suspect that you could do this with a bunch of Box layouts in nested JPanels.

For example, each label and text control pair would be its own JPanel with a vertical box layout and the three pairs would be nested in a JPanel with a horizontal box layout. (Flow might be just fine, too.) The buttons row would be in its own JPanel. I think you get the idea.